# systable for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there any system table to find the columns for `DDLChangeLog_ID, InsertionDate,CurrentUser, LoginName, Username, EventType, objectName, objectType, tsql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) or [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778(SQL.90).aspx)